# Align bootstrap thumbnail component

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using Bootstrap component, and facing some issues with aligning thumbnail components, due to text, that have various size.

My target is to have a sort of control panel, that display difference access, depending on user right (sometime 3 blocks are displayed, sometimes 10 blocks)

Here is the code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.2/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/template.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/bootstrap/js/bootstrap-filestyle.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js" charset="utf-8">     </script>     
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var height = 0;
        $(".col-md-4").each(function(){
          if (height < $(".col-md-4").outerHeight())
            height = $(".col-md-4").outerHeight();
        });
      $(".col-md-4").height(height);

</script>
</head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div style="text-align:center;" class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
          <div class="thumbnail"><img src="/images/fonctionnalites/degustations_300x200.jpg" alt="..." class="img-thumbnail">
            <div class="caption">
              <h3>Dégustations</h3>
              <p>Retrouvez les dernieres dégustations de votre reseau.</p>
              <p><a href="" class="btn btn-success btn-block">Afficher</a></p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
          <div class="thumbnail"><img src="/images/fonctionnalites/Vins_300x200.jpg" alt="..." class="img-thumbnail">
            <div class="caption">
              <h3>Vins</h3>
              <p>Retrouvez tous les vins de la base et leurs étiquettes</p>
              <p><a href="" class="btn btn-success btn-block">Afficher</a></p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
          <div class="thumbnail"><img src="/images/fonctionnalites/vignerons_300x200.jpg" alt="..." class="img-thumbnail">
            <div class="caption">
              <h3>Vignerons</h3>
              <p>Rencontrez les Vignerons français et leurs terroirs !</p>
              <p><a href="" class="btn btn-success btn-block">Afficher</a></p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
          <div class="thumbnail"><img src="/images/fonctionnalites/cavistes_300x200.jpg" alt="..." class="img-thumbnail">
            <div class="caption">
              <h3>Cavistes</h3>
              <p>Rencontrez les Cavistes français proches de vous !</p>
              <p><a href="" class="btn btn-success btn-block">Afficher   </a></p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here some screenshot depending on the screen size :

[image]

The 4th block is switched to right, due to different block height.

The when i resize the screen, and that all block text required 2 lines, their height become the same, and the world is perfect like this.

[image]

Question : how force this behavior in every screen configuration.

With the CSS (the standard one):

```
body {
  padding-top: 0px;
  padding-bottom: 75px;
  word-wrap:break-word;
}



.starter-template {
  padding: 40px 15px;
  text-align: center;

}

.bs-docs-example 
{
    position: relative;
    margin: 15px 0;
    padding: 39px 19px 14px;
    background-color: white;
    border: 1px solid #DDD;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
}

.bs-docs-example::after
{
    content: "Example";
    position: absolute;
```

Comment: Can you post the code of `/stylesheets/template.css`?

Comment: This is default css behavior. You have to have all the same height, or use flexbox, or a script to fix this behavior.

Answer (score 1):

This is a real problem when comes to Masonry style tiles. You can do it using JavaScript this way:

```
var height = 0;
$(".col-md-4").each(function(){
  if (height < $(".col-md-4").outerHeight())
    height = $(".col-md-4").outerHeight();
});
$(".col-md-4").height(height);
```

Comment: I added your script on the head node under a script node. but nothing changed (I'm novice in javascript at browser side...)  `<script type="text/javascript">
      var height = 0;
          $(".col-md-4").each(function(){
            if (height < $(".col-md-4").outerHeight())
              height = $(".col-md-4").outerHeight();
          });
          $(".col-md-4").height(height);
          
    </script>`

Comment: Nopes. You need to add this in the `$(document).ready(function(){});`